# nested subquery issue

Tags: sqlite

Shown below is the COMPANY table where i would like to extract the latest unique DEPT row records for a particular ID. The algorithm followed to achieve this requirement is mentioned below. Problem I am facing is that I am not able to figure out the 3rd step in the algorithm to be embedded as a nested query. Please suggest.

```
    ID             STATE    DEPT        DATETIME          yr_mon_date
    ================================================================     
    A8178         state2    Account  2016:09:01 14:11:44  2016:09:01 
    A8178         state3    Account  2016:09:01 15:12:50  2016:09:01 
    A8178         state3    Account  2016:09:01 16:11:33  2016:09:01 
    A8178         state3    Sales    2016:09:01 18:19:34  2016:09:01 
    A8178         state2    Sales    2016:09:01 18:28:50  2016:09:01 
    A8178         state3    Sales    2016:09:01 18:35:22  2016:09:01
```

## Algorithm

1. list all IDs that has DEPT = 'Sales'
2. for a particular DEPT(Sales) , select all IDs that have max(DATETIME);
3. from the obtained IDS, SELECT row that has max(DATETIME) and  DEPT <> Sales;

## Step:1 + Step:2

```
    select ID, STATE, DEPT, DATETIME, substr(DATETIME, 1, 10) yr_mon_date from COMPANY t1 
    where (STATE = 'state1' or STATE = 'state2' or STATE = 'state3' ) and 
    yr_mon_date = '2016:09:01' and DEPT = 'Sales' and DATETIME =
    (select max(t2.DATETIME) from COMPANY t2 where  t2.ID = t1.ID  );
```

## Expected output

```
    ID             STATE    DEPT        DATETIME          yr_mon_date
    ================================================================ 
    A8178         state3    Account  2016:09:01 16:11:33  2016:09:01 
    A8178         state3    Sales    2016:09:01 18:35:22  2016:09:01
```

Comment: Why does step 3 says "from the obtained IDs" when you want rows from *other* departments?

Comment: Intention is to find out the which other DEPT has processed with the same ID.

Comment: Your description and the expected output do not agree: there is a row with `DEPT='Sales'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong.
You want to retrieve the most recent records per ID per DEPT.
You can retrieve the most recent transactions by using the MAX function in a subquery.
And per ID per DEPT by joining on these columns in your subquery.

```
SELECT ID, STATE, DEPT, DATETIME
FROM COMPANY t1
WHERE DATETIME =
(
SELECT MAX(t2.DATETIME)
FROM COMPANY t2
WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
AND t2.DEPT = t1.DEPT
)
```

Comment: Thanks this works in general, however I want to have only those records that contain DEPT as 'sales' followed by any other DEPT. How do i achieve this.

Comment: My query returns the output you're looking for. If you're trying to tell (you're not being specifically clear) that the Sales department should come first, then I'd say "why bother, that is totally irrelevant".

Comment: This is a just a small part of the table, however the actual table contains huge data with many such DEPTS, the statistics has to be provided based on DEPT. so i just provided an instance of Sales as example.

Comment: Hopefully someone can help me on this.